# How to remove a tag and keep its childNodes on the same position (pure js)?

Tags: javascript

Lets have a text with a tag inside:

`<span>Homemade chicken noodle <span class="removeThisTag">soup</span> with potato</span>`

I want to remove the span tag (class="removeThisTag") so that its childNodes stay on the same position:

`<span>Homemade chicken noodle soup with potato</span>`

I guess its possible with remove() method and append the childNodes on the same position.

But maybe there is a simple way.

I've tried removeAttribute() but maybe I use it in wrong way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example the simplest is

```
parentSpan.textContent = parentSpan.textContent
```

like this

```js
const parentSpan = document.querySelector("span");
parentSpan.addEventListener("click", () => parentSpan.textContent = parentSpan.textContent); // to see it works
```

```css
span { border: 1px solid red }
```

```html
<span>Homemade chicken noodle <span class="removeThisTag">soup</span> with potato</span>
```

If you want to keep other markup:

```
remove.replaceWith(...remove.childNodes)
```

like this

```js
const parentSpan = document.querySelector("span");
const remove = parentSpan.querySelector(".removeThisTag");
parentSpan.addEventListener("click", () => remove.replaceWith(...remove.childNodes))
```

```css
span { border: 1px solid red }
```

```html
<span>Homemade chicken noodle <span class="removeThisTag"><i>soup</i></span> with potato</span>
```